# How to make the progressbar work, It freezes the window

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I tried making the progressbar but instead of working, it freezes the tkinter window, I also tried closing it but it froze the window

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time

root = Tk()


pbar = Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL,
                       length = 100, mode = 'determinate')


def bar():
    pbar['value'] = 20
    time.sleep(0.5)

    pbar['value'] = 40
    time.sleep(0.5)

    pbar['value'] = 60
    time.sleep(0.5)

    pbar['value'] = 80
    time.sleep(0.5)

    pbar['value'] = 100

pbar.pack()

Button(root, text = 'Start Bar', command = bar).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How to make it work !

Comment: use 'root.update()'

Comment: That is a very bad idea @HardikJain; the correct approach is to use `root.after` to launch a callback.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer seems to work, it locks your GUI during the 0.5 second `time.sleep` intervals.

A more straight forward way is to use `root.after`:

```
...

def bar():
    pbar['value']+=20
    if pbar["value"]!=100:
        root.after(500, bar)

pbar.pack()

...
```

Comment: Good use of `after` - you probably should protect against multiple button presses that would start the bar several times before it has time to complete. Use  `after_cancel`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to use `root.after`, while making sure that multiple button presses are dropped while the progress bar is active:

Here we are using a key word argument with default value to identify if the call originated from the button, or from a callback. We are also storing the callback id in a closure that is implemented via a mutable default value keyword argument; this allows us to cleanly cancel further callbacks when the work is complete.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def bar(btn=True, status=[None]):
    """activates and updates the progress bar status
    while making sure that multiple button presses only 
    start it once.
    """

    if btn and status[0] is not None:
        return 'break'
    elif pbar['value'] < 100:
        pbar['value'], status[0] = pbar['value'] + 1, root.after(10, bar, False)
    else:
        root.after_cancel(status[0])
        pbar['value'], status[0] = 0, None


root = tk.Tk()
pbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode='determinate') 
pbar.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Start Bar', command=bar).pack()
root.mainloop()
```